Notation for the function of a sequence is a function of its sub-sequences
I'm coming from a mainly biology background, please excuse my language. I am looking for a good notation of the following:
Lets say I have a sequence of nucleotides $s$ where each element of $s$ is A, G, C, T. For example, a sequence of ACGGGTCCA.
I want to represent this sequence as sub-sequences $w$ of length $k$. For example a $k=5$ of the above example results in [ACGGG, CGGGT, ... GTCCA].
I want to say that each sub-sequence which is at position $i\in (1,...,length(s)-k+1)$ has a value $v$ determined by a function given the position of the sub-sequence in the sequence: $v_i = g(w_i, p_i)$.
I finally want to say that the function of the sequence is the function of the values from its sub-sequences.
Would $f(s) = f(\{v_i\})$ be correct?
Any advice on how to clean up this notation is very appreciated.
EDIT: EXAMPLE
The sequence ACGGGTCCA results in an output of 40
We know that the reason for the output is from its sub-sequences. Each of its sub-sequences contributes to the final output which is based on its composition and its position in the sequence. Lets say the sub-sequences of ACGGG, CGGGT, ..., GTCCA contribute values of 5, 2, ..., 1, respectively. These values are then inputs of a function which produce the output of 40. The function can, for example, be the weighted sum. But it can also be some other function like a product.
So im trying to say that the output of a sequence is the function of the contributions of its sub-sequences.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Hi, thanks for your advice! I've applied tex format and also bolded my attempt/question.

With $k$ specified, maybe start by defining the function $W_m(s)$ which maps the sequence $s$ to its $m$th consecutive $k$mer.

Writing $f(s) = f(\{v_i\})$ would be, at the very least, confusing; you're using the letter $f$ for two entirely different things here.
It's not clear to me what you mean exactly by "the function of the sequence is the function of the values from its sub-sequences". What are you doing with these sequences' values?
I'd write something along the lines of:

Given a nucleotide sequence $S$, we will fix a length $k$, and look at all subsequences of length $k$. Let $s_{i}$ be the subsequence from the $i$-th to the $(i+k)$-th nucleotide.
We have a function $g$ that assigns a value to a subsequence, dependent on the subsequence itself as well its position. Let $v_i = g(s_{i},i)$. Then we assign a value $V$ to the whole sequence based on...

I'm not 100% sure if this works for your purposes - I don't know what your "position" $p_i$ is doing, or how you're getting a final score for the entire string. But hopefully something like this works as a starting point.

Thank you very much for your response! Its getting to what I'm looking for. I've added an example in the original question, please have a look.
